# Creating Codable object with Codable objects of any type?

Tags: swift, codable

I wish to create a class which will store a `Date` and any object that conforms to the `Codable` protocol. I would like this class to also conform to the `Codable` protocol itself.

I can do this for one object as follows:

```
class CodableContainerA: NSObject, Codable {
    var date: Date?
    var item: CodableTypeA?
}
```

I'd rather not have to create a separate CodableContainerX for each CodableTypeX I have.

My current workaround is to create a class called `CodableBaseClass` that conforms to `Codable`, derive every CodableType from it and define my class as follows:

```
class CodableContainer: NSObject, Codable {
    var date: Date?
    var item: CodableBaseClass?
}
```

This seems a long way around and feels like something I should be able to do by making the `CodableType`s conform to a protocol, but I'm not sure how. If I define `item` to be of type `Codable?` or `(Any & Codable)?` I get an error stating

`Type 'CodableContainer' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

I'm using Swift 4.

Any help or advice would be gratefully accepted. Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what generic classes are for:

```
class CodableContainer<T: Codable>: NSObject, Codable {
    var date: Date?
    var item: T?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you find yourself wondering about a separate class for each underlying type, think ["generics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179). E.g.

```
struct CodableContainer<T: Codable>: Codable { 
    let date: Date
    let item: T
}
```

- I'd use `struct` unless you needed `class` for some specific reason.
- I'd make the properties immutable unless you needed them mutable for some reason.
- I wouldn't subclass `NSObject` unless there was some specific reason that this particular container needed to be `NSObject` subclass.
- I'd make the properties non-optional unless you absolutely needed them to be optional.

But edit this as you see fit. The key point is the [generic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) pattern.

---

You might want a decoding function that decodes using some consistent `DateDecodingStrategy`, e.g.

```
extension CodableContainer {
    static func decodeJSON(_ data: Data) throws -> CodableContainer {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        return try decoder.decode(self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Obviously, use whatever `dateDecodingStrategy` you want. But then you can decode with:

```
let result = try CodableContainer<Foo>.decodeJSON(data)
```

Comment: I've marked Code Different's answer as the accepted answer as it was first and more concise but I do really appreciate your answer and suggestions and I have incorporated them into my code. These are all things I've wondered about today but I figured I'd get it working before I made it work well. Hopefully my code is now both! Many thanks.